# Creating a comment that gets displayed in generated request? WSDL SOAP xml

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui

Im in the process of writing a `wsdl` file for an existing system. I'd like to add comments to generated requests.

For instance this:

```
    <xsd:simpleType name="coffeetype">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <!--0=likescoffee,1=doesnotlikecoffe-->
            <xsd:enumeration value="0" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="CoffeeRequestInput" nillable="false" type="tns:coffeetype" />
```

Should look like this in the generated request: (eg. when loading the WSDL in SoapUI)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="https://example.com/some.wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <!--0=likescoffee,1=doesnotlikecoffe-->
      <wsdl:CoffeeRequestInput>0</wsdl:CoffeeRequestInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I was able to see these comments when opening the `WSDL` but not when generating a request from that `WSDL`.

Already looked into annotations but I wasn't able to use them to create the result I wanted. (Probably an error on my side)

Comment: You can add documentation to your xsd using xsd:documentation tag. See this link https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_documentation.asp. This is the standard way of documenting your requests,replies and structures. It wont appear in the request though.

Comment: @Namphibian I see. so there is no possibility to add comments to generated requests?

Comment: Not afaik. However you can generate some kick ass documents with a little xslt and those annotations.

Comment: @Namphibian please write this as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short you cannot create documentation in requests as you would like to. However you can generate documentation from your WSDL that can be be very useful. By using the "xsd:documentation" tag you can add documentation directly to the elements.

For example

```
<xsd:simpleType name="coffeetype">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">

        <xsd:enumeration value="0" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="CoffeeRequestInput" nillable="false" type="tns:coffeetype">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
          This object is the CoffeeRequestInput object is an Enumeration which can be used to determine is the user sending the request likes coffee or not. 
           Valid values for the enumeration is as follows:
           0 = like coffee
           1 = does not like coffee (probably a user not a programmer making a request).
           Some other things that you need to document goes here.
        </xsd:documentation>   
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

You can then use software such as Altova StyleForce, LiquidXML and OxyGen to generate PDF, Word documents or HTML pages which shows the SOAP services and operations with all your comments included.

If you feel up to it you can write your own XLST to transform your WSDL and XSD's into a neat HTML page which documents you interfaces as well. The best part about this is that when you update the WSDL with new operations and so on that the documentation is updated as well.